# How to append html id with for-loop?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm new to JavaScript and HTML. I'm reading my JSON file and appending it to each HTML ID but was wondering if there's an easier way to do this by using a for-loop?

```
  $("#vid0")
    .append(`<video src="${info.data[0].assets[3].url}" poster="${info.data[0].thumbnails[2].url}" muted>
        </video> 
        <h3 class="title">${info.data[0].metadata.title}</h3><h4 hidden class="description">${info.data[0].metadata.description}</h4>`);

  $("#vid1")
    .append(`<video src="${info.data[1].assets[3].url}" poster="${info.data[1].thumbnails[2].url}" muted>
        </video> 
        <h3 class="title">${info.data[1].metadata.title}</h3><h4 hidden class="description">${info.data[1].metadata.description}</h4>`);

  $("#vid2")
    .append(`<video src="${info.data[2].assets[3].url}" poster="${info.data[2].thumbnails[2].url}" muted>
        </video> 
        <h3 class="title">${info.data[2].metadata.title}</h3><h4 hidden class="description">${info.data[2].metadata.description}</h4>`);

  $("#vid3")
    .append(`<video src="${info.data[3].assets[3].url}" poster="${info.data[3].thumbnails[2].url}" muted>
        </video> 
        <h3 class="title">${info.data[3].metadata.title}</h3><h4 hidden class="description">${info.data[3].metadata.description}</h4>`);

  $("#vid4")
    .append(`<video src="${info.data[4].assets[3].url}" poster="${info.data[4].thumbnails[2].url}" muted>
        </video> 
        <h3 class="title">${info.data[4].metadata.title}</h3><h4 hidden class="description">${info.data[4].metadata.description}</h4>`);
```

Comment: If you show the entire code of the foor loop and data it might be easier to help. But in general it is in these situations you might start looking into a client rendering library like react or vue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterating over the changing indicies of 0 to 4 would look to do the trick.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    $(`#vid${i}`)
        .append(`
            <video src="${info.data[i].assets[3].url}" poster="${info.data[1].thumbnails[2].url}" muted>
            </video> 
            <h3 class="title">${info.data[i].metadata.title}</h3><h4 hidden class="description">${info.data[i].metadata.description}</h4>
        `);
}
```

If `info.data` will have the same number of items in the array as there are vid elements, a more elegant approach would be to give all such vid elements a class in common (such as `vid`), and then do

```
info.data.forEach((videoData, i) => {
    $('.vid').eq(i)
        .append(`
            <video src="${videoData.assets[3].url}" poster="${videoData.thumbnails[2].url}" muted>
            </video> 
            <h3 class="title">${videoData.metadata.title}</h3><h4 hidden class="description">${videoData.metadata.description}</h4>
        `);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this loop, i assume data is coming from an ajax call, and you got the payload inside the info variable.

```
$.each(info.data, function(i, vid){
    $("#vid" + i).append('<video src="${info.data[i].assets[3].url}" poster="${info.data[i].thumbnails[2].url}" muted></video> 
    <h3 class="title">${info.data[i].metadata.title}</h3><h4 hidden class="description">${info.data[i].metadata.description}</h4>');
});
```